# DoubleLinkedList with array String has generic element of Node

Tags: java, generics

I have a double linked node with one element and I implement this class `DNode` to my `DoubleLinkedList` class.

I have everything set up but I want to create a `DoubleLinkedList` where the `E` element is `String[2]`. How can I do this?

I want to do something like this:

```
package pt.ips.pa.model.modelo;

import pt.ips.pa.model.tads.DoubleLinkedList;

public class Ranking {
   private DoubleLinkedList<String[]> ranking;

   public Ranking() {
      this.ranking = new DoubleLinkedList<>();
   }    
}
```

`DNode` class is:

```
package pt.ips.pa.model.tads;

public class DNode<E> {

   private DNode<E> prev, next;
   private E elem;

   public DNode(E elem, DNode<E> prev, DNode<E> next) {
      this.elem = elem;
      this.prev = prev;
      this.next = next;
   }

   public DNode<E> getPrev() {
      return prev;
   }

   public void setPrev(DNode<E> prev) {
      this.prev = prev;
   }

   public DNode<E> getNext() {
      return next;
   }

   public void setNext(DNode<E> next) {
      this.next = next;
   }

   public E getElem() {
      return elem;
   }

   public void setElem(E elem) {
      this.elem = elem;
   }

}
```

here is the `DoubleLinkedList` class:

```
package pt.ips.pa.model.tads;

public class DoubleLinkedList<E> implements List<E> {

   private DNode<E> header;
   private DNode<E> trailer;
   private int size;

   public DoubleLinkedList() {
      this.header = new DNode<>(null, null, null);
      this.trailer = new DNode<>(null, header, null);

      this.header.setNext(trailer);
      this.size = 0;
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return this.size;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return this.size == 0;
   }

   @Override
   public E get(int r) throws OutofBoundsException {
      if (r < 0 || r >= this.size) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }
      return nodeAtRank(r).getElem();
   }

   @Override
   public E set(int r, E elem) throws OutofBoundsException {
      if (r < 0 || r >= this.size) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }
      DNode<E> nodeAux = nodeAtRank(r);
      E elemAux = nodeAux.getElem();
      nodeAux.setElem(elem);
      return elemAux;
   }

   @Override
   public E remove(int r) throws OutofBoundsException {
      if (r < 0 || r >= size) {
         throw new OutofBoundsException(r);
      }
      DNode<E> aux = nodeAtRank(r);
      E elem = aux.getElem();
      DNode<E> prev = aux.getPrev();
      DNode<E> next = aux.getNext();
      prev.setNext(next);
      next.setPrev(prev);
      size--;
      return elem;
   }

   @Override
   public void add(int r, E elem) throws OutofBoundsException {
      if (r < 0 || r > size) {
         throw new OutofBoundsException(r);
      }
      DNode<E> aux = nodeAtRank(r);
      DNode<E> prev = aux.getPrev();
      DNode<E> newNode = new DNode<>(elem, prev, aux);
      aux.setPrev(newNode);
      prev.setNext(newNode);
      size++;
   }

   private DNode<E> nodeAtRank(int r) throws OutofBoundsException {
      DNode<E> nodeAux = header.getNext();
      for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
         nodeAux = nodeAux.getNext();
      }
      return nodeAux;

   }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to include your default template license header comments in your question. There's a lot of code here but I'm not sure exactly what the question is.

Comment: i just want to create this: DoubleLinkedList<String[2]> how can i achieve this. Sorry for coments

Comment: You don't specify the size of the array in the type. That would just be a `DoubleLinkedList<String[]>` -- a DoubleLinkedList of String arrays.

Comment: But how can i after specify the size of it?

Comment: The Java type system doesn't allow you to limit a type to only arrays of a certain size. You specify the size when creating an array with the `new` operator, but if you have a variable of type `String[]` you can assign an array of any size to it.

Comment: ok but i declare the variable private **DoubleLinkedList<String[]> ranking** and then in the constructor i put this? **ranking = new DoubleLinkedList<String[2]>**

Comment: No, `ranking = new DoubleLinkedList<String[]>`

Comment: ok so when can i specify the size of it? Thx for all your help by the way

Comment: Wherever you actually create the `String[]` to put into the list, that's where you would specify the size of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `java.util.Pair` instead of `String[2]`. Otherwise you'll have to live with `String[]`.

```
DoubleLinkedList<Pair<String, String>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will do it:

```
DoubleLinkedList<String[]> ranking = new DoubleLinkedList<String[]>;
DNode<String[]> node = new DNode<String[]>(new String[2], null, null);
ranking.add(0, node);
```

I also suggest adding a second constructor to DNode which would just accept E element as parameter and also an append method the list class which would put the element at the trail position, then the code would simplify to:

```
DoubleLinkedList<String[]> ranking = new DoubleLinkedList<String[]>;
DNode<String[]> node = new DNode<String[]>(new String[2]);
ranking.append(node);
```

Also, as David Conrad noted, Java doesn't allow limiting the size of an array with Generics. Generic types basically get erased after compilation and are not present during runtime. Anyone can use your class DoubleLinkedList during runtime and add new DNodes containing string arrays of larger sizes.

If you really want to limit the size of the underlying arrays, you will have to change the code in DoubleLinkedList to perform (e.size <= 2) check if e is of array type. If you really want to do this, let me know in comments, I will show you the code for it. But it is not a clean solution and it would be better to have a non-generic, specialised list which only accepts String[] as type and performs the boundary checks.